# Full width on Flexbox nav won't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a flexbox site however for some reason the navigation won't appear in full width with a dark blue background color instead a box that centers:

[image]

I also need this navigation with the background sticky but don't know how to do it

Here's my CSS on this part:

```
.name {
    font-size: 1.35em;
    margin: 0;
}
.main-nav {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.name a,
.main-nav a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.main-nav a {
    font-size: .95em;
    color: #3acec2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-nav a:hover {
    color: #093a58;
}



/* ---- Layout Containers ---- */

.main-header {
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    background-color: red;
}
.banner,
.main-footer {
    text-align: center;
}
.banner {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #18bc9c;
    padding: 6.5em 0;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.col {
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
.main-footer {
    background: #d9e4ea;
    padding: 2em 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

/* ---- Page Elements ---- */

.logo {
    width: 256px;
}
.headline,.tagline {
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.feat-img {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

You can visit the sample FLexbox on JSFIDDLE site here: https://jsfiddle.net/6qg5vuux/3/

Do you know how to fix it and make it sticky?

Comment: you have set a fixed width  `@media (min-width: 769px) .main-header`, remove that an you'll be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put an `ID` to your `header` and then put the following `CSS`:

```
#header{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

I have set an `ID` because it has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). You could also do it using [!important exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) but this is not recommended and is not a good idea to abuse of it.

Also, remove your `max-width` property on your media query.

```css
/* ================================= 
  Base Element Styles
==================================== */

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.5;
 color: #e74c3c;
 margin: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

p {
 font-size: .95em;
}

h1{
 font-size: 4em;
}

h2,
h3,
a {
 color: #093a58;
}
h2,
h3 {
 margin-top: 0;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

/* ================================= 
  Base Layout Styles
==================================== */

/* ---- Navigation ---- */

.name {
 font-size: 1.35em;
 margin: 0;
}
.main-nav {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.name a,
.main-nav a {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
}
.main-nav a {
 font-size: .95em;
 color: #3acec2;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-nav a:hover {
 color: #093a58;
}



/* ---- Layout Containers ---- */

#header{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.main-header {
 padding-top: .5em;
 padding-bottom: .5em;
 background-color: red;
}
.banner,
.main-footer {
 text-align: center;
}
.banner {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #18bc9c;
 padding: 6.5em 0;
 margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.col {
 padding-right: 1em;
 padding-left: 1em;
}
.main-footer {
 background: #d9e4ea;
 padding: 2em 0;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

/* ---- Page Elements ---- */

.logo {
 width: 256px;
}
.headline,.tagline {
 margin: 0;
 color: #fff;
}
.feat-img {
 border-radius: 5px;
}


/* ================================= 
  Media Queries
==================================== */

@media (min-width: 769px) {
 .main-header,
 .row,
  .footer-inner{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .tagline {
  font-size: 1.4em;
 }
}


/* ================================= 
  Base Styles
==================================== */

body {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

.row {
 flex: 1;
}

/* ================================= 
  Media Queries
==================================== */

@media (min-width: 769px) {

 .main-header,
 .main-nav {
  display: flex;
 }
 .main-header {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
 }

}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {

 .main-header {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="main-header">
  <h1 class="name"><a href="#">MY SITE</a></h1>
  <ul class="main-nav">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
  </ul>
 </header><!--/.main-header-->   

 <div class="banner">
  <img class="logo" src="img/flex.png">
  <h1 class="headline">BOY</h1>
  <span class="tagline">VOILA THIS IS IT!</span>
 </div><!--/.banner-->
 
 <div class="row">  
  <div class="primary col">
   <h2>Welcome!</h2>
   <p>Everything in this city is worth waiting in line for!</p>
  </div><!--/.primary-->
 </div>
 
 <footer class="main-footer">
  <div class="footer-inner">
   <span>&copy;2015 Residents of The Best City Ever.</span>
   <p>Macaroon oat cake sugar plum liquorice sweet pastry bear claw. Biscuit candy liquorice toffee cupcake donut candy cupcake. Chupa chups marzipan ice cream jelly beans macaroon cookie bear claw. Lemon drops sweet cake pie powder bear claw topping. Wafer caramels bear claw chupa chups candy canes pastry apple pie. Liquorice croissant danish sweet roll cake jelly. Chocolate bar chocolate bar caramels cotton candy marzipan bear claw pudding. Icing icing jelly-o lemon drops.</p>
  </div>
 </footer>
```

Comment: Try running your code in full screen. It is not full width.

Comment: @niyasc Yes, you were right. I just was seeing it on the jsfiddle and did not notice about `max-width` property. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

```
/* ================================= 
  Media Queries
==================================== */

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .main-header,
    .row,
  .footer-inner{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1150px;
    }
```

and just change width from 80% to 100%.

Comment: and remove max-width

Comment: it did not work. I remove max-width as well but still the same

Comment: ¿?  works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/bvs0ed9x/1/ or see de answer of @Error404

Answer (score 0):

put in main-header `position:fixed;`